# User information is disabled (while using PHP Curl)

Tags: php, curl

I can access a web page when I type its URL in my browser. However, while using curl to access the details of that web page, I get the message on screen

```
User information is disabled.
This operation cannot be accepted. User certification is invalid or date expired.
Update page.
```

I can access the details of my network printer(Canon IR3570) by typing in the IP of that printer in my browser.  This opens up the remote UI. However, it doesn't seem to work with curl.

This is my code in PHP curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1');

$result= curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close ($ch);
```

What could be the reason for such a message?

Comment: Have you tried setting the curl option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false?

Comment: yes. i did that, but to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,1);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
```

Comment: Hey thanks @jipipayo. I am not connected to my network right now. i'll try that and comment on it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Where's UserAgent set? They may filtrate requests.

Comment: I am so sorry. I had already done that but forgot to put it in my code above(had them commented on my computer while experimenting)..just edited above.

Comment: I have been trying for quite a few days now..really tired of this..can't seem to get over it..anyways lets keep trying ;-)

Comment: Maybe install `Live HTTP Headers` plugin to `Firefox` and set all headers the same.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't CURL but it works in Visual Basic 2012 - one of the headers solved it for me

```
Sub Main()
    Dim web_client As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim baseDate As DateTime = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
    Dim diff As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - baseDate
    web_client.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "iR = 1711753823")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Host", "172.23.100.14")
    web_client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://172.23.100.14/jlp.cgi?Flag=Html_Data&LogType=0&Dummy=" & diff.Milliseconds)
    web_client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31")
    web_client.DownloadFile("http://172.23.100.14/pprint.csv?Flag=Csv_Data&LogType=0&Dummy=" & diff.Milliseconds, "P:\Transfer\mstavers\printlogs\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss") & ".csv")
End Sub
```